# opencv install folder on ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, opencv

I installed opencv2.3 on ubuntu by first adding the ppa and the  doing apt-get install

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gijzelaar/cuda
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gijzelaar/opencv2.3
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
```

I am developing on Eclipse and my programs work. I have this one problem though, while following an ebook. I cannot find the /opencv/samples folder in my system. I did a unix directory search to no avail.

Also, in Synaptic Package Manager I find that the opencv packages are not marked green, ie they're not installed. However I have written and executed opencv codes on my machine.

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have installed binary OpenCV package while the samples are (most likely) included only to source package.